# Selenium IDE - Set default speed to slow

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Everytime when I run Selenium IDE the speed control is set to "fast"
It is possible to set the speed control per default to "slow"?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Put this command in the beginning of your script:**

Command: setSpeed
Target: 3000

The IDE has a slow speed and a fast speed.  However, this is more precise so you can control the delay per command in milliseconds.  This example will have it wait 3 seconds per command.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on MacGyver's response, you can put the `setSpeed` anywhere in your tests, not just at the beginning. For example, you can use `setSpeed = 0` when checking for static elements on a page, then change `setSpeed` to something greater to test things like text entry, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use setspeed as variable, format is like this

```
store javascript{setspeed=250} SpeedFast
store javascript{setspeed=500} SpeedSlow
```

Then you can easily finetune speed by just changing in one place