# Slowing down Selenium IDE tests for instructional videos

Tags: selenium-ide

Is there a way to slow down Selenium IDE tests and record them so they can be used as instructional videos?

The default speed is configured for automated tests and is too fast for instructional videos.

If so, that would save a ton of work producing instructional videos, including updating those videos when the UI changes.

Also [posted in the Selenium IDE Google group](https://groups.google.com/g/selenium-users/c/s1SQHCPliMQ/m/WbxQmNsgAAAJ) (no response so far).

Updated: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6970983/667903) (thanks [Emmadi Sumith Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15987847/emmadi-sumith-kumar)) shows we can use:

```
Command: setSpeed
Target: 3000
```

I just need to work out how to:

- Remove the "Selenium IDE has started debugging this browser [cancel]" message.
- See if Selenium IDE can automatically record these videos.

Comment: Just FYI Playwright has slow mo mode which slows down each operation https://playwright.dev/docs/debug#headed-mode - also have you seen https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8451/how-can-i-reduce-the-execution-speed-in-webdriver-so-that-i-can-view-properly-wh

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735007/selenium-ide-set-default-speed-to-slow