# How to turn off "X has started debugging this browser" messages in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, selenium-ide

I'd like to [use Selenium IDE to automate web app instructional videos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76881077/667903) and need to turn off the **'Selenium IDE' has started debugging this browser** message that appears which will impact the video recording that occurs.

[image: Selenium IDE has started debugging this browser]

Checking: `chrome://flags/` and searching for `debug` I can see no relevant flag to alter.

Checking Google shows no solutions either.

If there's no way to turn this off I can probably delay the first step of the Selenium IDE test and then crop the first x seconds off the start of the video.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Try the --silent-debugger-extension-api flag when launching the browser

Comment: Thanks, @Martheen, how do I create a new alias on the desktop as `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --silent-debugger-extension-api` (I'm new to macOS)

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17476/how-can-i-force-command-line-arguments-to-a-program-shortcut-in-the-dock

Comment: Add an answer if you like @Martheen

Comment: You're in a better position to add the answer, I would have to reboot to macOS just to verify the syntaxes and menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/17477/5076):

> One way to do this is with AppleScript.
>
> Open AppleScript Editor (/Applications/Utilities/ScriptEditor) and
> type this in:
>
> ```
> do shell script "open '/Applications/Google Chrome.app'  --args --explicitly-allowed-ports=6666"
> ```
>
> Save it as an Application.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested solution by @Martheen worked, but the issue is when I restart the browser it flushes all cookie storage. The browser history is still there, so are the currently open tabs. But the cookies are not restored. First time it was starting it told me it can't access encrypted storage. Subsequent starts do not show this message but cookies are still reset. It's not MacOS keychain, I supposed, because there isn't anything saved under the browser.

When I reverse the solution and start the browser the regular way, the issue with cookies is resolved, re-starting the browser will again retain cookies and logins into sites.

I think somehow the browser checks if the executable in MacOS folder was tampered with, it if was, it doesn't allow accessing safe storage.

Wondering if there is any other option, other than running 2 separate browsers.